# UV problem - Texturing a Mountain

Tags: texturing, uv

I have an image where I cut out the background get only the mountain with a transparent background.

[image: mountain with transparent background]

I do a camera map for the mountain. The mountain mesh is a complete 3d mesh (it is not only a plane) and I do a UV from view. After that, I need to paint the texture in the 3d view, but I can't paint in 3d (because the 2D camera map), I get the image above. I need a complete 3d texture, like top view or something to manually paint. Something like this (but diffuse):

[image]

Comment: When creating the UV use the "Project from View" option while your view is looking straight down.

Comment: I doubt top view projections of mountain textures are very common. To begin with most people would use procedural materials for this, or for more stylized stuff paint it by hand.